# Adjusting thickness of lines in PlotLegends?

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

I have the following plot:

```
    Plot11 = 
 Plot[Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 1000}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {Placed[
     LineLegend[{Black, {Dashed, Black}}, {Style["Numerical", 
        FontSize -> 15], Style["Analytical", FontSize -> 15]}, 
      LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 5}], {0.5, 0.52}], 
    Placed[LineLegend[{RGBColor[34/255, 136/255, 51/255], 
       RGBColor[0, 68/255, 136/255]}, {Style["X", Black, 
        FontSize -> 15], Style["Y", Black, FontSize -> 15]}, 
      LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 5}], {0.8, 0.25}]}]
```

I am hoping to adjust the thickness of the different markers/lines comprising the legend.

For instance, how can I give the "Analytical" line a thickness of 0.005 (i.e., Thickness[0.005]) and the numerical line a thickness of 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Plot[Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 1000},
 
 BaseStyle -> 15,
 PlotRange -> {0, 1},
 
 PlotLegends -> {Placed[
    LineLegend[{Directive[Black, Thickness[1]], 
      Directive[Black, Thickness[0.005]]}, {"Numerical", 
      "Analytical"}, LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 5}], {0.5, 0.52}],
   
   Placed[
    LineLegend[{RGBColor[34/255, 136/255, 51/255], 
      RGBColor[0, 68/255, 136/255]}, {"X", "Y"}, 
     LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 5}], {0.8, 0.25}]}]
```

[image]